# Tenses Riddle question

Tags: tense

I was taking the [Verb Tense Final Test](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/verbs30finaltest.htm) when I came across a question that I didn't know the difference in the examples it contained.

> 1. Jane left when Tim arrived.
> 2. Bob left when Tim had arrived.
> 3. John had left when Tim arrived.
>
> Who did not run into Tim?

The answer is **John**. But I don't know why it cannot be Bob or Jane as well? 
Please tell me the difference among them.

Comment: So, this is a logic puzzle of sorts?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: This is about simple past and past perfect tenses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Arrive* and *leave* are both *eventive* verbs: they designate events, not states.
2. The perfect construction, however, is *stative*: it designates a state **at** Reference Time brought about by an event, or by the beginning of a state, **before** Reference Time. (Reference Time is the time you are talking about—in these sentences the time designated by the past tense verb.)
3. A state in a main clause modified by a *when* clause is understood to start before an event in the *when* clause and to overlap a state in the *when* clause.
4. An event in a main clause modified by a *when* clause is understood to follow an event in the *when* clause and to follow the *start* of a state in the *when* clause.

Consequently:

> Jane left when Tim arrived.

- an event (*left*) in the main clause
- an event (*arrived*) in the *when* clause
- Tim arrived, and some time after that Jane left.
- Jane and Tim were there simultaneously for some time.

> Bob left when Tim had arrived.

- An event (*left*) in the main clause
- A state (*had arrived*) in the *when* clause
- Tim had already arrived before Bob left.
- Bob and Tim were there simultaneously for some time.

> John had left when Tim arrived.

- A state (*had left*) in the main clause
- An event (*arrived*) in the *when clause
- John had already left when Tim arrived.
- John and Tim were never there simultaneously.

Comment: I agree for the most part. I'd argue that the first sentence is implying that Jane's departure occurred concurrently with Tim's arrival... so they may have said "hi" for two seconds before Jane departed but they weren't at the party at the same time for very long. Perhaps Tim is Jane's ex and she can't stand to be in the same room as him, so his arrival caused her to leave :P

Comment: @Catija Yes - it's probably a short time, but definitely Tim arrives before Jane departs.

Comment: Yes! No disagreement there.